# Unable to load assembly with windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a windows service in C# VS2008 that uses a reference to an external class library to wrote.  I have added the reference to it in VS2008.  When I run start the service it throws an exception when trying to access the external DLL:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'vcribAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The DLL is in the same directory as the service.exe file.  Is there something special that I need to do for windows services like putting the DLL in another directory?

Comment: Use the Fuslogvw.exe tool to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Is this at all related to the Virtual Crib project?  http://www.thevirtualcrib.com/

Comment: yup.  I am one of the main devs

Comment: Aha :) Looking at the plugin sample page, looks like the api require the mysql.data.dll, no? (http://www.thevirtualcrib.com/wiki/index.php?title=Create_a_Plugin_Guide)

Comment: Also another question, are you running the service on the same machine as your developing this or is it a different machine?

Comment: that is old.  i am working on something completely new.  Windows service with a plugin architecture to do all of the background processing.  You familiar with vCrib?

Comment: It is being run on my development machine

Comment: Nice. No, I just discovered it from the name of your dll :) Looking cool. Any luck with fuslogvw?

Comment: no luck with fuslogvw.  I have it set to log all binds to disk, but nothing ever shows up.

Comment: Does it work with a simple console app in the same folder?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I made sure the assembly was in /bin/debug and the service is running from /obj/debug.  I put the assemblies in that directory and all is working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that vcribAPI.dll relies on other assemblies as well. I suggest using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and open up the dll to see what other dll's it might reference.

Comment: I wrote vcribAPI so i know it doesn't rely on any other assemblies.

Comment: @Brian: ok, then yes, you should go with @nobugz comment: use fuslogvw.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx) to review the assembly binding log for clues.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same error.

The working directory of services is different from the application directory (typically C:\Windows\System32).

For example, the method `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName` throws a `FileNotFoundException` if you try to locate an assembly deployed in the application directory.

In this case, the solution is to define `Environment.CurrentDirectory` with the application directory before assembly loading.

Sample code :

```
const string SCHEMA_FILE = @"file:\";
var appAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(appAssembly.CodeBase);
if (path.StartsWith(SCHEMA_FILE))
    path = path.Remove(0, SCHEMA_FILE.Length);
Environment.CurrentDirectory = path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the assembly have other dlls or assemblies it depends on?

If so, they also need to be in this directory.

To be certain, start up the Assembly Loader Log (fusion log). See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) howto (Debugging Assembly Loading Failures).

Answer (score 0):

Does you service have rights to read in the folder?

Comment: It is the .Net runtime that loads the dll. If it can start the service exe, it will also be able to load dlls from that same folder.